# Mule Salesforce connector. Create Juntion Object using External IDs

Tags: salesforce, mule, mule-studio

I have the following Objects and fields.

Object A: External Id (a_ext_id) and other fields 
Object B: Extrernal Id (b_ext_id) and other fields 
Custom Junction Object C: External id (c_ext_id) and fields a__c (lookup(a)), b__c (Master-Detail(b)) and Status__c

I would like to upsert records into Junction Object C without having to know the Salesforce Ids of Object A and Object B.

I just got it working with Partner WSDL.

Is there anyway to upsert in Mule without writing Java code?

Answer (score 0):

External ID's can be used to achieve this. I would suggest use dataweave before the Salesforce connector and submit external id of the parent objects as shown below: (assuming payload have the external ID values)

`{
    c_ext_id: payload.cExt,   // Value: C's external ID from payload
    a__r: {
        a_ext_id: payload.aExt // value: A's External ID from payload
        },
    b__r:{
        b_ext_id: payload.bExt // value: B's External ID from payload
    }, 
    status__c: payload.status 
}`